# Making cyrillic readable for the Scanner Object in Java

Tags: java, encoding

My issue is that when I input cyrillic letters into the Scanner, that when I try to print it out it becomes gobbldygook (Eg. input ходить, output = Ö–æ–¥–∏). I have the Ascii values of the cyrillic alphabet as well as the UTF-8 values stored in a text file. I am pretty certain that System.in is wrong, so what exactly should I be doing?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = s.nextLine();
System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting charset for the Scanner? new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8")?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it is the same result

Comment: Then it's your output device.  If you're printing to a Windows terminal it will produce garbage unless you convert back to the correct codepage on output.  Your output looks like you're trying to print UTF-8 without encoding it for the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

(I apologize in advance for my english)
I had the same problem. I working with "eclipse"  and text file encoding is UTF-8. When I input cyrillic text from the console and when I try to print it the output result is similar like yours.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in,  "UTF-8");
      String word = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println(word);
```

result:

```
дума
РґСѓРјР°
```

The two lines must be same but they aren'n.

My resolve is:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in,  "UTF-8");
      String word = input.nextLine();

      try {
        word = new String(word.getBytes("windows-1251"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      System.out.println(word);
```

result:

```
дума
дума
```

This is the right result.

I'm sorry but my english is very poor...
I hope I helped you.

Comment: What if you started with `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in,  "windows-1251");`?

Comment: My explanation is that "windows-1251" is the best encoding for the input language (cyrillic) . When we try to print word with this encoding the result not correct because the Scanner encoding and "eclipse" settings are for "UTF-8".  We have to convert word to "UTF-8" which is set in "eclipse" like text file encoding. I'm sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: If I start with Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in, "windows-1251"); the result is almost the same (inscrutables symbols)