# hasNext() returns false, even though the file is not empty

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read some `.txt` files, but `hasNext()` always returns `false`.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 126; i++)
{
            StringBuilder currentSong = new StringBuilder();
            try 
            {
                String name = i + ".txt";
                File file = new File(name);
                if(file.exists())
                {
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);


                    while(input.hasNext())                         //this gets skipped
                    {
                        currentSong.append(input.nextLine());
                    }

                    if(!input.hasNext())                          //this executes
                    {
                        Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
                        d.open(file);
                    }


                    PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter("new/" +  i + ".txt");
                    write.write(currentSong.toString());
                    write.close();
                    input.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No file was found");
                }


            } 

            catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

when the program opens the file, it is not empty, and has text, but when I run in, it `hasNext()` returns false...

this is the content of the first file, and the rest follow a similar template. These are Russian songs:

```
1
Ты искупил мир от греха,
И дал ему любовь и свет
Зажёг потухшие сердца
и дал надежду.
Мы пред Тобою предстоим
и каждый дорог для Тебя,
За все, Отец, благодарим
и превозносим.

/bПрипев:
/bСлава Тебе и величье,
/bСлава в веках и народах,
/bСила твоя безгранична,
/bМилость Твоя во все роды.

Ты открываешь новый мир
любви, надежды и красоты.
С Тобой не трудно мне идти –
ведь Ты со мною.
Мы пред Тобою предстоим
и каждый дорог для Тебя,
За все, Отец, благодарим
и превозносим.

/bПрипев:
/bСлава Тебе и величье,
/bСлава в веках и народах,
/bСила твоя безгранична,
/bМилость Твоя во все роды.
```

Comment: what is the actual file content?

Comment: try hasNextLine()

Comment: [tag:awt] has exactly nothing to do with it. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: How do you know it gets skipped? The second block is always executed because the first loop finishes only when `!input.hasNext()`. The `if`there is useless, as it is always true.

Comment: @JohanWitters I have tried that too, didnt work either

Comment: @bezmax because i put a brake point there, and dtbbeged it

Comment: The `Scanner` class looks for *tokens*. Maybe it has a problem with the files *encoding*. If you don't need access to the individual words you might get the files content with `Files.readAllLines(file)`

Comment: What encoding does the file use?   Open the file using that character set.  See: [`Scanner(File file, String charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I think @TimothyTruckle and @AJNeufeld are correct. After saving your Russian song using `UTF-8`, and using `UTF-8` for both input and output, the text was copied (without new-line characters, mind you). Without specifying `UTF-8` nothing was copied (I'm on Windows and `UTF-8` is not the default encoding) probably because the `Scanner` couldn't properly parse the input (it uses whitespaces by default).

Comment: Maybe `if(input.hasNextLine){ currentSong.append("\n" + input.nextLine()) }`?

Comment: Try and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898578/making-cyrillic-readable-for-the-scanner-object-in-java), also... maybe a duplicate.

Comment: I will request moderator level, to edit the title suitable for the thread issue, thanks in advance and happy new year 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Universal Alphabet (`UTF-8`) charset is not good for `Cyrillic` type Alphabet so either this `utf-8` ignores the character or result some other kind of different char from the source.

In your case, you are reading a `Russian` as per `google.translate.com auto detect` and I have tested my source code on 10+ languages and received the output similar to the input file,

in `eclipse` console will only show `?` because it supports plain `english charset` as per my knowledge, not even `utf-8` also,

Input.txt placed inside src directory -

```
1   Russian
Ты искупил мир от греха,
И дал ему любовь и свет
Зажёг потухшие сердца
и дал надежду.
Мы пред Тобою предстоим
и каждый дорог для Тебя,
За все, Отец, благодарим
и превозносим.

2   English
Jack and Jill
Went up the hill
To fetch a pail of water
Jack fell down
And broke his crown,
And Jill came tumbling after
Up Jack got,
And home did trot
As fast as he could caper;
To old Dame Dob,
Who patched his nob
With vinegar and brown paper.

3   Chinese
钱唐湖春行

孤山寺北贾亭西
水面初平云脚低
几处早莺争暖树
谁家新燕啄春泥
乱花渐欲迷人眼
浅草才能没马蹄
最爱湖东行不足
绿杨阴里白沙堤

4   Urdu
کبھی تم مجھ سے ملتے ہو
توڑنا مت کرو،

زندگی آپ کے ساتھ جاتا ہے،
مسکر اندر ہے ...

ایم .سرپر میرپوری

5   Hindi
पुष्प की अभिलाषा
- माखनलाल चतुर्वेदी
चाह नहीं मैं सुरबाला के
गहनों में गूँथा जाऊँ
चाह नहीं, प्रेमी-माला में
बिंध प्यारी को ललचाऊँ
चाह नहीं, सम्राटों के शव
पर हे हरि, डाला जाऊँ
चाह नहीं, देवों के सिर पर
चढ़ूँ भाग्य पर इठलाऊँ
मुझे तोड़ लेना वनमाली
उस पथ पर देना तुम फेंक
मातृभूमि पर शीश चढ़ाने
जिस पर जावें वीर अनेक ।।

6   Korean
초겨울 편지/ 김용택

앞산에
고운 잎
다 졌답니다
빈 산을 그리며
저 강에
흰눈
내리겠지요
눈 내리기 전에
한번 보고 싶습니다

7   Tamil
புத்தாண்டு வாழ்த்துக்கள்
பூக்கட்டும் புதுமலர்,
வீசட்டும் நம்மில்!!
இனிக்கட்டும் திருநாள்,
பிறக்கட்டும் புதுசிந்தனை!!
போகட்டும் பகைமை,
இனையட்டும் உறவு!!
விலகட்டும் தாழ்வு,
வாழட்டும் மனிதம்!!
தோன்றட்டும் வாய்ப்பு,
அடையட்டும் இலக்கு!!
பரவட்டும் அமைதி,
மாறட்டும் புதிய புத்தாண்டு!!

8   Marathi
चल माणसा भाकीत कर
मन तुझं उघड कर
जगण्याचा प्रवाह शिथिल कर
सुकर कर सुजय कर

9   Bengali
ঘোর কেটে গেলে
- আবিদ আনোয়ার
হয়তো এখনও আছি অর্ধস্ফুট গোলাপের মতো-- 
বোঝেনি শরীর-সত্তা কাকে বলে পূর্ণ জাগরণ;
দরিদ্র ইন্দ্রিয়গুলো চিনেছে যে বস্তুবাস্তবতা
কখনও জাগ্রত হলে চিনে নিতো আরেক জীবন। 
যদি এ-রহস্যমালা কোনোদিন এই গূঢ় অন্তর্বাস খোলে
হয়তো দেখবো কিছু বর্গক্ষেত্র ঢুকে বসে আছে
অসংগত পৃথিবীর বেমক্কা বর্তুলে:
প্রকৃত রাজার কাঁধে গোলামের তকমা তুলে দিয়ে
গোলাম রাজত্ব করে জগদ্দল প্রভুত্বের পতাকা উড়িয়ে।
দিব্যদৃষ্টি খুলে গেলে তুমি দেখে নিয়ো

10  German
Der Weg nicht genommen:

Zwei Straßen wichen in gelbem Holz aus,
Und tut mir leid, ich konnte nicht beide reisen
Und sei ein Reisender, lange habe ich gestanden
Und schaute so weit ich konnte nach unten
Zu wo es sich im Unterholz verbog;

11  Punjabi
ਲੋਹੜੀ ਦੇ ਗੀਤ

ਸੁੰਦਰ ਮੁੰਦਰੀਏ - ਹੋ
ਸੁੰਦਰ ਮੁੰਦਰੀਏ - ਹੋ!
ਤੇਰਾ ਕੌਣ ਵਿਚਾਰਾ - ਹੋ!
ਦੁੱਲਾ ਭੱਟੀ ਵਾਲਾ - ਹੋ!
ਦੁੱਲੇ ਧੀ ਵਿਆਹੀ - ਹੋ!
ਸੇਰ ਸੱਕਰ ਆਈ - ਹੋ!
ਕੁੜੀ ਦੇ ਬੋਝੇ ਪਾਈ - ਹੋ!
ਕੁੜੀ ਦਾ ਲਾਲ ਪਟਾਕਾ - ਹੋ!
ਕੁੜੀ ਦਾ ਸਾਲੂ ਪਾਟਾ - ਹੋ!
ਸਾਲੂ ਕੌਣ ਸਮੇਟੇ - ਹੋ!
ਚਾਚਾ ਗਾਲ੍ਹੀ ਦੇਸੇ - ਹੋ!
ਚਾਚੇ ਚੂਰੀ ਕੁੱਟੀ - ਹੋ!
ਜ਼ਿੰਮੀਦਾਰਾਂ ਲੁੱਟੀ - ਹੋ!
ਜ਼ਿੰਮੀਦਾਰ ਸਦਾਓ - ਹੋ!
ਗਿਣ ਗਿਣ ਪੌਲੇ ਲਾਓ - ਹੋ!
ਇੱਕ ਪੌਲਾ ਘਟ ਗਿਆ!
ਜ਼ਿਮੀਂਦਾਰ ਨੱਸ ਗਿਆ - ਹੋ!
```

and I used the `Cyrillic (ISO) - charset=iso-8859-5` for reading and writing, so here is my source code -

```
package com.practice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("src/Input.txt");
            File outputFile = new File("src/Output.txt");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                            (new FileInputStream(inputFile), "iso-8859-5"));

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter
                            (new FileOutputStream(outputFile), "iso-8859-5"));

            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                writer.write(line + "\n");
            }

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please don't abuse me, if you don't find example on some particular language, it is just for testing and helping purpose,

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do, but I imagine that you have some text file, and you are having trouble reading lines from this same text file. It also looks as if you are trying to re-write this original textfile into a new file. If this is the case, I would recommend breaking down the code into a more manageable and test friendly sections. For example, first check to make sure you are correctly reading the text file, by printing it to the console log:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

//reads each line from a .txt file and prints to console log
//using hasNext() as condition to while statement (while hasNext() is still true)

public class exampleScannerHasNext
{//end class
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {//start main

   String eachLineRead;
   File file = new File("johnLennon.txt");
   Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

   while(inputFile.hasNext())
   {    
      eachLineRead = inputFile.nextLine();
      System.out.println(eachLineRead);
   }
   inputFile.close();
   }//end main
}//endclass
```

I am using this text file named "johnLennon.txt" :

```
Imagine there's no heaven
It's easy if you try
No hell below us
Above us only sky
Imagine all the people
Living for today... Aha-ah...

Imagine there's no countries
It isn't hard to do
Nothing to kill or die for
And no religion, too
Imagine all the people
Living life in peace... You...

You may say I'm a dreamer
But I'm not the only one
I hope someday you'll join us
And the world will be as one

Imagine no possessions
I wonder if you can
No need for greed or hunger
A brotherhood of man
Imagine all the people
Sharing all the world... You...
```

Then, once you have proven to yourself that the problem is not with hasNext(), then you can start adding more features to your code, such as the try catch statements, if the file exist or not, and even writing the strings to a new file. I would be happy to further elaborate on the expansion of your code. Just let me know and we can write the method together. 
-James